# How can I convert a file into an array2D?

Tags: java, arrays, list, matrix, type-conversion

I´m using Java 11, and this is file i need to convert to array2D:

> {1 4},{10 20}
>
> {1 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 2 5},{3 9 1 4}
>
> {10 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 2 5},{3 9 1 4}
>
> {1 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 5 5},{3 9 1 4}

The idea of the conversion is to transform each line into an independent matrix, which type has to be `int[][]`

I have already converted the file into a List, but i can´t turn that List into the array2D.

This is what i tried to do:

```
        for(int i=0;i<text.size();i++) {
            String line = text.get(i);
            line = line.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
            line = line.replace(" ", "").replace(" ", "");
            String[] part = line.split(",");
            System.out.print(part[i]);
}
```

and this is the result:

14

3377

6425

3914

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. You're more likely to get a response if you detail what research you took to try to find a solution.  Please format your code. Please see the Stack Overflow Question Guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `String` method  [`split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) may be your best friend here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You split on commas and white-spaces:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines("YourFilePath", Charsets.UTF_8);
    lines.forEach(System.out::println);
    lines.forEach(s -> {
        String[] rows = s.split(",");
        int[][] array2D = new int[rows.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length ; i++) {
            String[] column = rows[i].trim().replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(" ");
            int[] ints = new int[column.length];
            for (int j = 0; j < column.length; j++) {
                ints[j] = Integer.parseInt(column[j]);
            }
            array2D[i] = ints;
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array2D));
    });
```

The output:

{1 4},{10 20}

{1 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 2 5},{3 9 1 4}

{10 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 2 5},{3 9 1 4}

{1 4 2 0},{3 3 7 7},{6 4 5 5},{3 9 1 4}

[[1, 4], [10, 20]]

[[1, 4, 2, 0], [3, 3, 7, 7], [6, 4, 2, 5], [3, 9, 1, 4]]

[[10, 4, 2, 0], [3, 3, 7, 7], [6, 4, 2, 5], [3, 9, 1, 4]]

[[1, 4, 2, 0], [3, 3, 7, 7], [6, 4, 5, 5], [3, 9, 1, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<List<List<String>>> vectorize(List<String> lines){
    List<List<List<String>>> vector = new ArrayList<List<List<String>>>();
    for (String line: lines) {
        List<String> dimensions = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
        List<List<String>> row = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        for (String dimension: dimensions) {
            row.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(dimension.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").trim().split(","))));
        }
        vector.add(row);
    }

    return vector;
}
```

try this one